# Using generics in an Expression<Func<MyType, TOrderBy>> in a Constructor

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0, constructor, func

This is probably a relatively simple oversight, but I can't work out if I'm actually allowed to do this, or what might be a reasonable alternative (using  in VS2010, C# .Net 4.0). I would strongly prefer to do this in the constructor if at all possible.

This is my class:

```
public class MyClass1<TOrderBy> : MyInterface1<MyType1, MyType2>
{
    public MyClass1(IEnumerable<Guid> ids) : this(ids, 0, 10, a => a.Time, ListSortDirection.Ascending) { }

    public MyClass1(IEnumerable<Guid> ids, int pageIndex, int itemsPerPage, Expression<Func<MyType2, TOrderBy>> orderBy, ListSortDirection sortDirection)
        {
            this.pageIndex = pageIndex;
            this.itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;
            this.orderBy = orderBy;
            this.sortDirection = sortDirection;
            this.ids = ids != null ? ids.ToList() : new List<Guid>();
        }
}
```

I get the error

`Cannot convert expression type 'System.DateTime' to return type 'TOrderBy'` when hovering over `a => a.Time`

and the errors `Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<MyType2,TOrderBy>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type` and `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'TOrderBy'` when building.

As you can probably work out, I'm trying to build a class that takes information in the constructor to sort and page an IQueryable.
I want to supply defaults via overloaded constructors. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What is the type of `a`?

Comment: `a.Time` should have the type `TOrderBy`. No fooling the compiler here. This a common issue/mistake, in your case a complex scenario.

Comment: If you are sure `TOrderBy` is always a `DateTime` (which in itself indicates some other design issue) you can cast like `(TOrderBy) ((object) value)`.

Comment: @cofiem, @leppie: If `TOrderBy` is always a `DateTime` then it's likely that `MyClass1` doesn't need to be generic at all.

Comment: @Gabe the type of `a` is `MyType2`, which has a Property `Time` of type `DateTime`.

Comment: @LukeH: Exactly what I meant in the parenthesised part.

Comment: @leppie @LukeH TOrderBy is unknown, which is why it's generic. It won't always be `DateTime`, it might be `int` or `TimeSpan`.

Comment: @leppie from your first comment, you're saying that I'm not able to use TOrderBy in the Expression<Func<>> get it to work out the type of the property? It works fine in a .OrderBy, which is where it ends up.

Comment: @cofiem: The problem is with the 'small' constructor. `DateTime` is not compatible with `TOrderBy`. So, if you are sure, when using that specific constructor that `TOrderBy` will always be `DateTime` (which it kind of implies, I guess), then the cast will do, and there should be no performance penalty.

Comment: @leppie That cast does compile (I replaced `a => a.Time` with `a => (TOrderBy)(object) a.Time`, but what is it doing? It looks like it's effectively determining the type of TOrderBy by casting a known type to an unknown type. That looks weird...

Comment: How does the compiler know that a `MyType2` has a `DateTime Time` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a => a.Time
```

Time is a `DateTime`.  `TOrderBy` might not be a `DateTime`, for example:

```
MyClass1<Car> x = new MyClass1<Car>(ids);
```

So, you can't do what you're trying to do.

---

That `TOrderBy` is a big pain!  The best idea would be to avoid the problem by not having a `TOrderBy` as part of the class if you can help it.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7742446/8155) shows a way to wrap the ordering expression to hide the TOrderBy from the outside world.

Comment: You link to the answer about wrapping the order expression looks like the way to go. Can that be modified to include the order (asc, desc) in the constructor of `Orderer<T, U>`?

Comment: @cofiem yes, it could.  the point is to use an interface with one type parameter to reference a class that has two type parameters.