# Generic Func<T,K> to sort collections of different types

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I have many collections for many types I want to sort each collection by different properties.   For example `IEnumerable<Employee>` will be sorted by `Name` and `Age` properties,and  `IEnumerable<Department>` will be sorted by `NumberOfEmployees` and `DepartmentName` properties. I use `PaginatedList` to paginating the collection after sorting it.

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
{
  public PaginatedList(IEnumerable<T> source, Int32 pageIndex, Int32 pageSize , Func<T,Object> orderBy)
  {
    this.AddRange(source.OrderBy(orderBy).Skip((PageIndex - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize));
  }
}
```

Note the 4th parameter which is the sorting delegate that will be passed to OrderBy extension method.

I am using a generic method to generate this 4th element

```
public Func<T, Object> SortingFactory<T>(String sortby) 
{
  switch (typeof(T).ToString())
  {
    case "Employee":
      switch(sortby)
      {
        case "Name":
           return new Func<Employee,String>(delegate(Employee e) { return e.Name; });
           break;                            
        case "Age":
           return new Func<Employee,Int32>(delegate(Employee e) { return e.Age; });
           break;
      }
      break;
    case "Department":
      switch(sortby)
      {
        case "NumberOfEmployees":
           return new Func<Department,Int32>(delegate(Department d) { return d.NumberOfEmployees; });
           break;                            
        case "DepartmentName":
           return new Func<Department,String>(delegate(Department d) { return d.DepartmentName; });
           break;
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

but it gives me a compilation Error`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Func<Employee,String>' to 'System.Func<T,object>'`

I also tried to decalre the output as `Func<Object,Object>` but I got the same error.

What is the fault I made and how do such method.

Comment: #1: you are not showing us the line where the error occurs. #2: `SortingFactory` is simply hideous and has no reason to exist. How is writing `.OrderBy(SortingFactory<Employee>("Name"))` better than writing `.OrderBy(e => e.Name)`?

Comment: @Jon No `SortingFactory` has reason to exist. using `.OrderBy(e => e.Name)` is not generic I need to use `PaginatedList<T>` to all collection I have.

Comment: @Jon .OrderBy(SortingFactory<Employee>(userSuppliedString))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say I understood well

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
{
  public PaginatedList(IEnumerable<T> source, Int32 pageIndex, Int32 pageSize )
  {
    this.AddRange(GetOrderFor<T>().Skip((PageIndex - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize));
  }
}

public static class Helpers
    {

        public static Func<T, object> GetSortExpression<T>(string sortExpressionStr)
        {
            var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T), "x");
            var sortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(param, sortExpressionStr), typeof(object)), param);
            return sortExpression.Compile();
        }

        public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> GetOrderFor<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
        {
            switch (typeof (T).Name)
            {
                case "Employee":
                    return list.OrderBy(GetSortExpression<T>("Name")).ThenBy(GetSortExpression<T>("Age"));
                case "Category":
                    return list.OrderBy(GetSortExpression<T>("Name")).ThenBy(GetSortExpression <T> ("Id"));
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And if I misunderstood, I think the simple usage of GetSortExpression method can help you to avoid your error

```
case "Employee":
      switch(sortby)
      {
        case "Name":
           return Helpers.GetSortExpression<T>("Name");                           
        case "Age":
           return Helpers.GetSortExpression<T>("Age");
      }
```

Comment: I think even if you misunderstand me, the first approach is better,but I am not sure,Is `Expression.Compile` has performance drawbacks

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your code stems from trying to convert between generic types. The solution given here should avoid that.

You should be able to make use of the `Comparer<T>` class. Here is an example for sorting `Employee`s:

```
class EmployeeComparer : Comparer<Employee>
{
    string property;

    public EmployeeComparer(string Property)
    {
        this.property = Property;
    }

    public override int Compare(Employee x, Employee y)
    {
        switch (this.property)
        {
            case "Name":
                return Comparer<string>.Default.Compare(x.Name, y.Name);
            case "Age":
                return Comparer<int>.Default.Compare(x.Age, y.Age);
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The `DepartmentComparer` would be very similar.

EDIT: Here is the `property` field abstracted to a base class, with the revised `EmployeeComparer`:

```
abstract class PropertyComparer<T> : Comparer<T>
{
    protected string property;

    public PropertyComparer(string Property)
    {
        this.property = Property;
    }
}

class EmployeeComparer : PropertyComparer<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeComparer(string Property) : base(Property)
    {

    }

    public override int Compare(Employee x, Employee y)
    ...
}
```

Then you could write a function to get a comparer for the required type:

```
Comparer<T> GetComparer(string Property)
{
    // Sadly, you cannot switch on a Type
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Employee))
    {
        return new EmployeeComparer(Property) as Comparer<T>;
    }
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(Department))
    {
        return new DepartmentComparer(Property) as Comparer<T>;
    }
    else
    {
        return Comparer<T>.Default;
    }
}
```

That would most likely belong in the `PaginatedList` class:

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
{
    Comparer<T> GetComparer(string Property)
    ...

    public PaginatedList(IEnumerable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize, string orderBy)
    {
        Comparer<T> comparer = GetComparer(orderBy);
        this.AddRange(source.OrderBy(x => x, comparer).Skip((PageIndex - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize));
    }
}
```

HTH. I didn't test it, but if you find a bug, just comment.

Comment: your answer is so simple but with it I have to write a `Comparer<T>` for each type in my application. Is There way to write just one `Comparer` class?

Comment: Not that I know of. The EmployeeComparer class is quite simple, and you can easily create copies of it for different types, without too much work.

Comment: Yes I can copy it but what about [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)

Comment: The only thing that is being repeated is the `property` field. If you don't want to have that repeated, I will add some code for putting that in a base class.

Answer (score 1):

You need a more generic version of `SortingFactory`, one that will return a lambda of any type. Basically this converts a string into a strongly typed Expression usable for sorting:

```
public Expression<Func<T, To>> SortingFactory<T, To>( String sortby )
{
    // Entity type
    System.Type dataType = typeof( T );

    // Entity - main parameter (x =>
    ParameterExpression rootExp = Expression.Parameter(dataType, "x" );

    // property (x => x.Property
    PropertyInfo pi = dataType.GetProperty( sortby );

    // put together
    Expression expr = Expression.Property( rootExp, pi );
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, To>>( expr, rootExp );
}
```

I don't have it in, but you may want to check that `pi` is not null. This also assumes the incoming string is a scalar property, not an Entity or a collection - that get's a bit trickier.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Func<Employee,String>' to 'System.Func<T,object>'
> ```

This error is telling you that `Func<X, string>` does not inherit from `Func<X, object>` (even though string inherits from object).  This is a very common Generics mistake!  `List<Customer>` does not inherit from `List<object>`.  If it did, you could get away with this:

```
List<Customer> c = new List<Customer>();
List<object> x = (List<object>) c;
x.Add(x)
//List<object> is-a object, so the statement is valid,
//  but a List<Customer> is not a Customer, breaks the instance referenced by c
// instead of breaking c's instance, you get a runtime exception on line 2 - invalid cast.
```

---

Many answers are turning to expression maniupulation stuff.  I feel that is too heavy of a hammer to swing at this problem...

What you need to do is remove/hide that second generic parameter, as I have done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737355/store-multi-type-orderby-expression-as-a-property/7742446#7742446).

```
public interface IOrderer<T>
{
  IOrderedEnumerable<T> ApplyOrderBy(IEnumerable<T> source);
  IOrderedEnumerable<T> ApplyOrderByDescending(IEnumerable<T> source);
  IOrderedEnumerable<T> ApplyThenBy(IOrderedEnumerable<T> source);
  IOrderedEnumerable<T> ApplyThenByDescending(IOrderedEnumerable<T> source);
} 

public class Orderer<T, U> : IOrderer<T>
{
  private Func<T, U> _orderFunc;
  public Orderer(Func<T, U> orderFunc)
  { _orderFunc = orderFunc; }
  public IOrderedEnumerable<T> ApplyOrderBy(IEnumerable<T> source)
  { return source.OrderBy(_orderFunc); }
  public IOrderedEnumerable<T> ApplyOrderByDescending(IEnumerable<T> source)
  { return source.OrderByDescending(_orderFunc); }
  public IOrderedEnumerable<T> ApplyThenBy(IOrderedEnumerable<T> source)
  { return source.ThenBy(_orderFunc); }
  public IOrderedEnumerable<T> ApplyThenByDescending(IOrderedEnumerable<T> source)
  { return source.ThenByDescending(_orderFunc); }
}
```

Then your method:

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
{
  public PaginatedList(
    IEnumerable<T> source,
    Int32 pageIndex, Int32 pageSize,
    IOrderer<T> orderer)
  {
    IEnumerable<T> query = orderer.ApplyOrderBy(source)
      .Skip((PageIndex - 1) * PageSize)
      .Take(PageSize)  
    this.AddRange(query);
  }
}
```

Or, when you want multiple sorting (as will inevitably happen), this:

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
{
  public PaginatedList(
    IEnumerable<T> source,
    Int32 pageIndex, Int32 pageSize,
    List<IOrderer<T>> orderers)
  {
    IEnumerable<T> query = source;

    if (orderers.Any())
    {
      IOrderer<T> firstOrder = orderers.First();
      IOrderedEnumerable<T> orderedQuery = firstOrder.ApplyOrderBy(source);
      foreach(IOrderer<T> nextOrder in orderers.Skip(1))
      {
        orderedQuery = nextOrder.ApplyThenBy(orderedQuery);
      }
      query = orderedQuery;
    }

    this.AddRange(query.Skip((PageIndex - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize));
  }
}
```

After that, you just need to add some property to IOrderer and Orderer so that it knows if it should be asc/desc, and you should have ordering all wrapped up.

---

(more fun, your sorting factory)

```
public IOrderer<T> SortingFactory<T>(String sortby)
{
  switch (typeof(T).ToString())
  {
    case "Employee":
       switch(sortby)
       {
         case "Name":
            return new Orderer<Employee, string>(e => e.Name); //hmm, not sure this will work.
            break;
```